# On mouser over tooltip box breaking bar values react-chartjs-2/chartjs

Tags: javascript, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs

Here I'm facing the issue in the horizontal chart using react-chartjs-2/chartjs.
The issue is on page load char loads the bar along with its value as excepted but when I do on hover on the bar to display the tool-tips all bar values are getting disturbed/flickering.

Thanks

Please find the screenshot attached for reference.
first screenshot working fine and the second one having an issue.

> [image: Blockquote]

[image]